# Grey on black is really hard to read (rep in top bar)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Since we graduated, I find the top bar numbers (rep and badge counts) really hard to read. I don't notice this on other graduated sites:

[image: assorted top bars and logos]

I actually find scifi pretty hard to read because the flare goes right through the number. But the rest of them have better contrast, and some seem to use bold.

Can we make the numbers in our top bar a lighter colour so they are easier for these old eyes to read, please?

Comment: I feel like this is a convenient way to show off how much rep you have across the network ;) (kidding, I'm impressed!)

Comment: I did think about that for a moment, but I don't have access to anyone else's rep to use as example :-). I actually omitted my second-highest site since it didn't look that different from some I'd used already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the reputation score significantly lighter. The change is now on our dev server, will be on live after the next production build(sometimes this evening).